# how to load a variable of an module in dashboard

Tags: php, mysql, pyrocms

I am using pyroCMS and i have module A and in that i have a controller, I am getting some values in $var which i defined in function index(), How to load the controller in a different module, I have to use the variable in the controller in my dashboard view

Here is my controller code in module A

```
public function index()
{
$data = $this->recent();
}
```

dashboard.php view file

```
<div class="accordion-body collapse in lst" style="overflow: auto;">
<?php print_r($data );?>
</div>
I am not getting $data in dashboard.php
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.2/manual/developers/addons/modules/basic-structure), it should be something like this:

```php
public function index()
{
    $data = $this->recent();
    $this->template
        ->set('data', $data)
        ->build('dashboard');
}
```

**Edit:**

To have a module load data when a user visits the dashboard you need to use [events](http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.2/manual/developers/tools/events). The following hook should be called when loading the dashboard.

```
Events::register('admin_controller', array($this, 'run'));
```

Comment: i have already added this in my module controller am getting all the data, i need to load a view files written in some other module in dashboard